# CALL of the command from C in WINCE

Tags: c, batch-file, windows-ce

I am trying to call `cd dirname` from .exe under wince, but unsuccessfully. Any idea how to do it? My current solution just print desired command, but not execute it.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x = 0;
    // PARSE SOME FILE to get x
    x = getX();
    printf("START \"cd %d\"", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `cd 110`

Deisred output: Execution of: cd 110

Comment: `printf` is only used for printing text to a output. To execute this you would need to use something like `exec()`

Comment: There is a standard function to execute "commands". ***But*** it won't help you, as it usually creates a new process, and changing directory is local to a single process and won't affect any other processes. Besides, on almost platforms the `cd` command is built-in in a shell/command-line environment and usually not something that can be called. I don't know about WinCE, but try something like the [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) instead.

Comment: Windows CE does not support the concept of a "current directory" and `SetCurrentDirectory` or `GetCurrentDirectory` are not available.